# Unable to replace the content in String Builder

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I am having two string builders in which one holds the complete data and the other holds the data that should be replaced but I am unable to replace the content.

This is the code i have written

```
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();

sb1.AppendLine("1111111111");
sb1.AppendLine("555555555");
sb1.AppendLine("666666660");
sb1.AppendLine("6666666601");
sb1.AppendLine("6666666602");
sb1.AppendLine("6666666603");
sb1.AppendLine("888888888");
sb1.AppendLine("99999999");
sb1.AppendLine("555555555");
sb1.AppendLine("666666661");
sb1.AppendLine("666666662");
sb1.AppendLine("666666663");
sb1.AppendLine("666666664");
sb1.AppendLine("888888888");
sb1.AppendLine("99999999");

sb2.AppendLine("6666666601");
sb2.AppendLine("666666661");

sb1 = sb1.Replace(sb2.ToString().TrimEnd(charRemove), "");
sb1 = sb1.Replace(sb2.ToString(), ""); // this also i tried
```

I would like to *remove* `sb2` content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mustn't use `StringBuilder` for sb2.

To make it short, you are telling .NET to replace `6666666601666666661` in `sb1`.

Try:

```
List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
list2.Append("6666666601")
list2.Append("666666661")

foreach (var str in list2)
{
    sb1.Replace(str + "\r\n", ""); // the \r\n are because you used `AppendLine`
}
```

(and I'm not even sure you want to use a `StringBuilder` for sb1. `StringBuilder` is used to "compose" strings, not to "collect" them)

Note that this is still wrong wrong wrong!

You would be much better to begin the sb1 with an empty line, like this:

```
sb1.AppendLine("");
```

so that you can Replace like this:

```
sb1.Replace("\r\n" + str + "\r\n", "\r\n"); // the \r\n are because you used `AppendLine`
```

in this way, `99` won't mach `1999`, because `1999` will be `\r\n1999\r\n` while `99` will be `\r\n99\r\n` (we are adding a blank line at the beginning of the `StringBuilder` so that even the first element is preceeded by a `\r\n`. We are replaceing with `\r\n` because we are matching TWO `\r\n`, one before and one later, but one of the two must be preserved.)

I'll add that perhaps you simply exchanged `StringBuilder` for a collection of `string`s, and perhaps you wanted to do this:

```
List<string> str1 = new List<string>();
str1.Add("555555555");
str1.Add("666666660");
str1.Add("6666666601");
str1.Add("666666661");

List<string> str2 = new List<string>();
str2.Add("6666666601");
str2.Add("666666661");

str1.RemoveAll(p => str2.Contains(p));
```

Answer (score 2):

The string held in `sb1` does not contain the string `"6666666601666666661"`, so there is nothing to replace.

If you are trying to replace all instances of the two strings `"6666666601"` and `"666666661"` that exist in the string held in `sb1`, you should replace each at a time.

```
string str1 = sb1.ToString();
str1 = str1.Replace("6666666601");
str1 = str1.Replace("666666661");
```